# What does "[*]" (star modifier) mean in C?

Tags: c, function, parameters, variable-length-array

While trying to implement a C11 parser (for educational purposes), I found that in [C11 (p. 470)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) but also in [C99 (p. 412)](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/Spring13/CSCI-GA.2110-001/downloads/C99.pdf) (thanks Johannes!), the *direct declarator* is defined as:

```
(6.7.6) direct-declarator:  
    direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list? * ]
```

At first, I thought this was an error in the grammar (the type list shouldn't be optional). However, when I tried this out in my reference compiler (clang), I got an rather unexpected error:

```
int array[*] = { 1, 2, 3 };
// error: star modifier used outside of function prototype
```

So apparently, (in clang) this is called the *star modifier*.

I quickly learned that they can only be used in function signatures:

```
void foobar(int array[*])
```

However, they can only be used in the declaration. Trying to use it in a function definition results in an error as well:

```
void foobar(int array[*]) {
    // variable length array must be bound in function definition
}
```

---

So as far as I can tell, the intended behaviour is to use `[*]` in the function declaration and then use a fixed number in the function definition.

```
// public header
void foobar(int array[*]);

// private implementation
void foobar(int array[5]) {

}
```

---

However, I have never seen it and I don't quite understand the purpose of it either.

1. What is its purpose, why was it added?
2. What's the difference with `int[]`?
3. What's the difference with `int *`?

Comment: It's been in C since C99. I believe it means "placeholder for VLA number here". `int[][]` is not valid, but `int[][*]` is (in a non-defining function prototype).

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention it but I searched for the errors that I got from clang and they corresponded to their VLA unit test suite. Still, I would like to know their purpose. Thanks!

Comment: 22 views and this is already the first google result for "c star modifier". You've hit upon an obscure feature.

Comment: Since when is Clang "the reference compiler"?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish there's other questions about it, this is the first time someone called it "star modifier" though

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think he meant it in any specific capacity, just that it was the compiler that he personally is using to check that his interpretation of the standard is sane.

Answer (score 43):

> What is its purpose, why was it added?

Purpose is seen when a variable length two dimentional array is used as a function parameter. The function

```
int foo(int n, int m, int a[n][m])  {...}
```

can be prototyped as any of the following

```
int foo(int , int, int [][*]);
int foo(int , int, int a[*][*]);
int foo(int , int, int (*a)[*]);
int foo(int n, int, int a[n][*]);
int foo(int , int m, int a[*][m]);
int foo(int , int m, int (*a)[m]);
int foo(int n, int m, int a[n][m]);
```

In case of two dimensional array, when used as function parameter, size of the second dimension can't be omitted. If the name of first variables in function prototype is omitted then it wouldn't be possible to specify the length (second dimension) of the array. The `*` gives the clue that the length of the array will be determined by the second parameter.

> What's the difference with `int[]`?
> What's the difference with `int *`?

In case of 1D array, for the function definition

```
int bar(int n, int a[n]} {...}
```

any of the following prototype is valid

```
int bar (int , int *);
int bar (int , int [*]);
int bar (int , int []);
int bar (int n, int a[]);
int bar (int n, int a[n]);
int bar (int n, int [n]);
```

In  this case neither `*` nor `n` is necessary as compiler will treat both of `int [*]` and `int [n]` as `int *`. So, with one dimensional array you can't see much difference.

---

NOTE: When using variable length array as a function parameter, order of parameter is important. Order of parameters for first four prototypes of `bar` can be switched, but in latter two first parameter must not be the array itself.

```
int bar (int a[n], int n);  //Wrong. Compiler has not yet seen 'n'.
```

Comment: This directly answers the question instead of just quoting a standard.

Comment: The standard quote directly answers the question, and it's authoritative, because it's from the standard. There's nothing wrong with standard quotes. (Come to think of it, that quote's from the rationale document, not the standard, though.)

Comment: @user2357112 there was another answer not by me who directly quoted the Standard. I guess alvits refes to that. Mine doesn't quote the C standard, as you correctly point out

Comment: `int bar (int [*], int);` is correct.

Comment: It's not that there's anything *wrong* with quoting the standard, *per se*. In fact, it's usually a good idea. The problem comes when the answer consists solely of a quotation from the standard without any sort of explanation. Generally, if someone was able to read and understand exactly what was meant by the standard, they wouldn't be asking a question about it on Stack Overflow. So a good answer (to a question where it is relevant) really needs to do both. If you had to choose one or the other, I'd have to agree with alvits and say that an explanation is superior to a quotation.

Answer (score 16):

The C rationale document for C99 says

> A function prototype can have parameters that have variable length array types (§6.7.5.2) using a special syntax as in
>
> ```
> int minimum(int, int [*][*]);
> ```
>
> This is consistent with other C prototypes where the name of the parameter need not be specified.

---

> What's the difference with int[]
>
> What's the difference with int *.

I think it's simply that those types in a function prototype means "pointer", while a `[*]` in a non-top position (`int[*]` still equals `int[]` I think, in a function prototype) actually is valid and *means* array

```
// not recommended though: it is now unclear what the parameters
// mean to human callers!
void f(int, int [][*]);

void f(int n, int x[][n]) {
    x[1][0] = 1;
}

int main() {
   int a[2][1];
   f(1, a);
   printf("%d\n", a[1][0]);
}
```

As for the purpose, when indexing the array in the function definition, the compiler needs to know how many integers of the next index to skip when giving the first index  (`x[i]` skips `i * n` integers in `f` above). But this information is not needed in the non-defining prototype declaration, hence it can be left out and replaced by `*`.

Comment: Your function prototype should be `void f(int, int x[][*])`. When you give the first parameter a name, then there's no need for the `*`. The whole point of this feature is that you can use old fashioned function prototypes that don't name the parameters.

Comment: @user3386109 hmm, was naming the parameters not allowed in C89? I thought this was always allowed? Why woud leaving out names be "old fashioned"? But, true, the motivation is less high if you name the parameter anyway